# Stop Angular Material Autocomplete from updating input

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material

I am creating a country autocomplete input. I would like to abstract the input into a component using the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. I want to use this component to take a `FormControl<string | null>` where string is a ISO_3166-2 string and null means no selection.

[image: Interaction with parent]

There are three main parts in the component:

- List of options (filtered) - `{code: string; name: string;}[]`
- Selected value (changes input when selected) - `string | null`
- Input value (free-text, sets selected value to null on change) - `FormControl<string>`

[image: Expected state]

Currently, when a user selects an autocomplete item it sets the input's `FormControl<string>` to the object selected (e.g. `{code: 'US', name: 'United States'}`), which obviously is not `FormControl<string>` type. Is there a way to handle the autocomplete selection and the input value completely separately?

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ju6qw9?file=src/app/country-input/country-input.component.ts

*In this example, I have used a `FormControl<Country>` instead of a `FormControl<string>` for the input value, but I am still not getting the desired result because the FormControl is string on runtime after user inputs free text. The filtering functionality is also omitted for simplicity.*

Comment: What is the expected value when a user select an autocomplete item? Should it be `United States`?

Comment: @skouch2022 The expected value of the input is `United States` (see second diagram, step 2), however the value emitted by the ControlValueAccessor should be `US`. That's the main thing I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to handle the autocomplete selection and the input value completely separately?

You can use `optionSelected` of the `mat-autocomplete`. This is an event emitter that will emit only when the option is selected. This allows you to manage when to update the `selected`'s value.

#### Example.component.html

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [formControl]="selected" [matAutocomplete]="auto" value=""/>

  <mat-autocomplete 
    #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    [displayWith]="displayFn" 
    (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event)">

      <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
        {{country.name}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>

</mat-form-field>
```

#### Example.component.ts

```js
@Component({
 ...
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  
  ...

  public onOptionSelected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {

    console.log(event.option.value);
    // do something with the value here.
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but unfortunately still changes the text input value. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: @AndreyTsarev Isn't that how autocomplete is supposed to work? You enter `chin` into the input, then select `china` from the autocomplete. Your input should be `China`. Do you expect the input to be still `chin` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own `AutocompleteInputDirective` for the input field of the `mat-autocomplete` where you provide the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and the `MatFormFieldControl`.
You can then listen to the `input` event on the HostElement (the HTMLInput element) but also subscribe to the `optionSelected` observable of the `matAutocomplete` (which you can require by using a selector like `input[myAutocompleteInput][matAutocomplete]`).

Now you are able to differ between user-entered search query values (which can be emitted to a dedicated event emitter) and actually selected option values, which can be emitted to the FormControl (`_onChangeFn` from `ControlValueAccessor`).
It doesn't matter whether you are using objects as values or specific string values (enums, isoCodes) - only the "actual" values or null will be set to the FormControl.
**Additionally the `MatFormField`/`MatLabel` will correctly show the errorState of the source `FormControl` and also add the `*` to the label when required.**

Usage like this:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>My Autocomplete</mat-label>

  <input
    type="text"
    myAutocompleteInput
    [formControl]="myFormCtrl"
    (query)="filter($event)"
    [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete"
  />

  <mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete">...</mat-autocomplete>

</mat-form-field>
```

the directive ...

- provides the `EventEmitter` `query` for the user search query
- sets the value on the `myFormCtrl` when an option was selected
- sets null on the `myFormCtrl` when the user changes the input field value

see [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-input-directive?file=src/autocomplete-input.directive.ts) - might be helpful

The [`MatChipGrid`](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples#chips-form-control) is essentially doing the same to prevent emitting plain user queries. I find it surprising that Angular Material still doesn't offer a such a solution for the MatAutocomplete ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

When the input is focused you can change the value before being displayed.

This is not a very good solution, but I hope it helps.

**Template:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput
  [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  [formControl]="fcInput"
  (focus)="onInputFocus()">

  <mat-autocomplete #auto>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
        {{country.name}}
     </mat-option>
 </mat-autocomplete>
```

**Component:**

```
countries: Country[] = ...;
fcInput = new FormControl<String|null>(null);

onInputFocus(): void {
   if (this.fcInput.value instanceof Object) {
      let country: Country = <Country>{};
      Object.assign(country, this.fcInput.value);
      this.fcInput.setValue(country.name);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this is how I got around it.
The default behavior - in html, assign `optionSelected` method to a func:

```html
<mat-autocomplete
   ...
   (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
```

and in the component's `.ts` you reset the input control for the form the `matInput` belongs to (assuming you're using one):

```js
selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
   //this is the important bit vvvv
   this.myFormControl.reset();**
        ...
   //custom logic to handle selected value using event.option.value
        ...
}
```

Resetting the form for me instantly got rid of the value.
However, if you're using multiple fields, I assume reset gets rid of those fields too, unfortunately.

edit: my whole html code is

```html
<form id="inputForm">
    <mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
        <mat-label>Add a site...</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          [formControl]="myFormControl"
          #input
          [(ngModel)]="siteInputValue"
          (keyup.enter)="add()"
          [matAutocomplete]="auto" />

        <mat-autocomplete
           (opened)="setFilterList()"
           #auto="matAutocomplete"
           (optionSelected)="selected($event)">

           <mat-option
             [value]="site.id"
             *ngFor="let site of siteInputFilterList | async"
           >{{ site.name }}</mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```